# Implement to_s of Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array, tostring

Ruby's Array class has the built-in method to_s that can turn the array into a string. This method also works with multidimensional array. How is this method implemented?

I want to know about it, so I can reimplement a method **my_to_s(ary)** that can take in a multidimensional and turn it to a string. But instead of returning a string representation of the object like this

```
[[[1,2,3, Person.new('Mary')]],[4,5,6,7], Person.new('Paul'),2,3,8].to_s
# [[[1, 2, 3, #<Person:0x283fec0 @name='Mary']], [4, 5, 6, 7], #<Person:0x283fe30 @name='Paul'>, 2, 3, 8]
```

**my_to_s(ary)** should call the to_s method on these objects, so that it returns

```
my_to_s([[[1,2,3, Person.new('Mary')]],[4,5,6,7], Person.new('Paul'),2,3,8])
# [[[1, 2, 3, Student Mary]], [4, 5, 6, 7], Student Paul>, 2, 3, 8]
```

Comment: I actually believe that you just want to override `Person#to_s` to return `"Student #{self.name}"` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested elements it just calls `to_s` respectively:

```
def my_to_s
  case self
  when Enumerable then '[' << map(&:my_to_s).join(', ') << ']'
  else 
    to_s # or my own implementation
  end
end
```

This is a contrived example, that nearly works, if this `my_to_s` method is defined on the very `BasicObject`.

---

As suggested by Stefan, one might avoid monkeypathing:

```
def my_to_s(object)
  case object
  when Enumerable then '[' << object.map { |e| my_to_s(e) }.join(', ') << ']'
  else 
    object.to_s # or my own implementation
  end
end
```

---

More OO approach:

```
class Object
  def my_to_s; to_s; end
end

class Enumerable
  def my_to_s
    '[' << map(&:my_to_s).join(', ') << ']'
  end
end

class Person
  def my_to_s
    "Student #{name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Or `object.map { |o| my_to_s(o) }` to avoid the monkey patching.

Comment: And you probably want to surround the nested output with `'['` and `']'`.

Comment: @Stefan indeed, thanks, I have updated the answer (for both monkeypatched version and external method.)

Comment: For more object oriented approach, you could alias `my_to_s` to `to_s` for `Object` and override it in `Enumerable`

Comment: This is weird: for some reason, `alias_method  :my_to_s, :to_s` (or `alias  my_to_s to_s`) does not work, whereas `def my_to_s; to_s; end` does.

Comment: @Stefan `alias_method` works for me. `class Object; alias_method :my_to_s, :to_s; end; 5.my_to_s` ⇒ `"#<Fixnum:0x0000000000000b>"`. Ah! It works, but it strictly maps to `Object#to_s`.

Comment: @Stefan yes, it looks like the polymorphism is broken and it just produces a “hardlink” to `Object#to_s`. Funny.